# How to Create or convert to a DataSet to a Dataset[Row]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset, apache-spark-dataset

Hello im trying to test the following function that takes in a Dataset[Row] as a paramter

```
 def getReducedSubsidiaries(dsSubsidiaries: Dataset[Row])(implicit spark: SparkSession): Dataset[SubsidiariesImpacted] = {
    import spark.implicits._
    dsSubsidiaries.as[SubsidiariesImpactedStage]
      .groupByKey(_.subsidiary_uuid)
        .reduceGroups((a, b) => if (a.event_timestamp.compareTo(b.event_timestamp) >= 0) a else b)
        .map(_._2)
        .select(
          $"subsidiary_uuid",
          $"subsidiary_id",
          $"company_uuid"
        )
        .as[SubsidiariesImpacted]
  }
```

Im trying to create a DataSet to pass in through this function but i'm not sure how to convert this Dataset which i created into a Dataset[Row] which is what it needs.

```
      val ts1 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-08-01 00:00:00")
      val ts2 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-09-20 00:00:00")
      val ts3 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-11-27 00:00:00")
      val subsidiaries:Dataset[SubsidiariesImpactedStage] = Seq(
        SubsidiariesImpactedStage(ts1,"active","sub_uuid1",32L,"comp_uuid1"),
        SubsidiariesImpactedStage(ts2, "inactive","sub_uuid1",32L, "comp_uuid1"),
        SubsidiariesImpactedStage(ts3, "active", "sub_uuid1", 5L, "latest_comp_uuid1")
      ).toDS()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dataset.toDF()`

```
case class SubsidiariesImpactedStage(t : Timestamp, a: String, b:String, c : Long, d :String )

    val ts1 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-08-01 00:00:00")
    val ts2 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-09-20 00:00:00")
    val ts3 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-11-27 00:00:00")

    val subsidiaries:Dataset[SubsidiariesImpactedStage] = Seq(
      SubsidiariesImpactedStage(ts1,"active","sub_uuid1",32L,"comp_uuid1"),
      SubsidiariesImpactedStage(ts2, "inactive","sub_uuid1",32L, "comp_uuid1"),
      SubsidiariesImpactedStage(ts3, "active", "sub_uuid1", 5L, "latest_comp_uuid1")
    ).toDS()

    val df = subsidiaries.toDF()
    println(df.getClass)
    df.show()
```

Result- dataframe is Dataset[Row]

```
class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
+-------------------+--------+---------+---+-----------------+
|                  t|       a|        b|  c|                d|
+-------------------+--------+---------+---+-----------------+
|2019-08-01 00:00:00|  active|sub_uuid1| 32|       comp_uuid1|
|2019-09-20 00:00:00|inactive|sub_uuid1| 32|       comp_uuid1|
|2019-11-27 00:00:00|  active|sub_uuid1|  5|latest_comp_uuid1|
+-------------------+--------+---------+---+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Dataframe is DataSet[Row] (>spark 2.0)

so just convert Seq to DF instead of DS before passing as a argument to function.

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
def fun(d:Dataset[Row])=d.show()
fun(Seq(Person("a", 1)).toDF())
```